# Installing/Uninstalling spring-security-eventlog-0.3

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

I am having some trouble setting up spring security in my application so I tried to install spring-security-eventlog-0.3 in order to see the logs and understand what the hell is going on :))))
I added this line in BuildConfig.groovy

```
compile ":spring-security-eventlog:0.3"
```

When I hit run-app I get this very beautiful message

```
SpringSecurityEventlogGrailsPlugin.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils
 @ line 3, column 1.
   import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils
   ^
SpringSecurityEventlogGrailsPlugin.groovy: 2: unable to resolve class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SecurityEventListener
 @ line 2, column 1.
   import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SecurityEventListener
```

The run failed. I decided to remove it because I didn't feel like spending hours for that. The thing is that even though I removed the line from BuildConfig, it tries to install it every single time! I even went in my hard disk's path and removed the folder. Even though it installs it every time and fails of course.
Could you please suggest me a solution on this? I would prefer to keep the plugin and be able to have the spring security logs. If it is not possible for some reason, I would like to be able to remove it.

Comment: Have you tried `grails refresh-dependencies`?

Comment: Are you using `spring-security-core:2.0-RC2`? The eventlog plugin uses `spring-security-core:1.2.7.3` where package structure for `SpringSecurityUtils` is different from the later version. `grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils` in version `2.0-RC2`.

Comment: If you really want to use the plugin then clone it and update spring-security-core in it (you might come across blockage issue because of compatibility) or I would not use it if it is much of an hassle. But I would not suggest to downgrade your spring-security-core to the older version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, that plugin depends on version 1.2.x of the core plugin, so you either need to downgrade to 1.2.7.3, or wait until the eventlog plugin is updated to use the 2.0 plugin.

I updated the plugin and [sent a pull request](https://github.com/ataylor284/spring-security-eventlog/pull/3), and hopefully the author will release an updated version soon. Feel free to bug him about this if he doesn't :)

Comment: Thank you for the accurate answer. What should I do until the eventlog plugin is updated? I am not able to remove the plugin whiche means I cannot start the application at the moment and I would not like to downgrade to 1.2.7.3. - I should maybe ask a separate question for that

Comment: The plugin isn't compatible, so you either have to remove it, or use the older core plugin, or wait for the update. Andrew merged in the changes from my pull request, so hopefully he'll update soon.

Comment: Version 0.4 has been released with Burt's fixes.